# the first while loop works but it doesnt proceed to the next while loop right below it

Tags: c, while-loop

```c
void main() {
    int y = 0;
    char password[30], username[40], total_items[10000], input_item,
        ip11[] = "-IPhone 11\n", ipX[] = "-IPhone X\n";
    char ap[] = "-AirPods\n", chrg[] = "-Charger\n";
    char scrpro[] = "-Screen Protector\n", reset_str[] = " ";
    int i = 0, total_amount = 0, auth = 4;

    while (auth > 10)
        ;
    {
        printf("Enter Username:");
        scanf("%s", &username);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter password:");
        scanf("%s", &password);
        fflush(stdin);
        if ((strcmp(username, "admin") == 0) &&
            (strcmp(password, "admin123") == 0)) {
            auth += 7;
        } else {
            printf("Invalid password or username\n");
            printf("%d tries left\n", auth);
            auth -= 1;
        }
    }
    while (y > 5) {
        printf("Welcome,These are the items that we sell:\n");
        printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("a. IPhone X - $1200 \nb. IPhone 11 - $1500\n");
        printf(
            "c. AirPods - $300 \nd. Charger - $15 \ne. Screen Protector - "
            "$20\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("To buy, key in the alphabet beside the item.\n");

        printf("Please input 1 item at a time\n");
        while (i < 10) {
            printf("Enter item wanted(input 'z' to finish cart):");
            scanf(" %c", &input_item);

            if ((input_item == 'a') || (input_item == 'A')) {
                total_amount += 1200;
                strcat(total_items, ipX);
            } else if ((input_item == 'b') || (input_item == 'B')) {
                total_amount = total_amount + 1500;
                strcat(total_items, ip11);
            } else if ((input_item == 'c') || (input_item == 'C')) {
                total_amount = total_amount + 300;
                strcat(total_items, ap);
            } else if ((input_item == 'd') || (input_item == 'D')) {
                total_amount = total_amount + 15;
                strcat(total_items, chrg);
            } else if ((input_item == 'e') || (input_item == 'E')) {
                total_amount = total_amount + 20;
                strcat(total_items, scrpro);
            } else if ((input_item == 'z') || (input_item == 'Z'))
                i += 10;
            else
                printf("Invalid item, please input again\n");
        }
        printf("Your total is: $%d\n", total_amount);
        printf("Your items are:\n%s\n", total_items);
        printf("Please collect your receipt and head over to the counter\n");
        printf("Thank you for coming to OneTop!\n");
        printf("\n");
        strcpy(total_items, reset_str);
    }
}
```

I expected the code to proceed to the second while loop but the code instead just crashes.

Comment: I reformatted your code, which now makes the presence of a `;` after the first `while` very apparent. If this is your code, this is likely your problem. You should also compile with `-Wall` or similar, which complains about that line (among other things).

Comment: Also should be noted that you never enter the first (currently infinite) loop, since `auth == 4`, and `(4 > 10)` is false.

Comment: `while(cond) ;` is just a loop with an empty body, entirely equivalent to `while(cond) {};`.

Answer (score 3):

### Incorrect format specifier:

```
scanf("%s", &username);
```

`username` is a constant pointer to the first element of the array. There's no need to use the `&` operator with it.

### Stray semicolon:

The statement:

```
while (auth > 10)
        ;
```

is equivalent to saying:

*"While `auth` is greater than `10`, do nothing."*

It's dead code.
The block of code after the `while` loop will always execute, irregardless of the value of `auth`.

Even if you were to remove the semi-colon, the program would never enter the loop, as:

```
auth == 4
```

And the condition:

```
if (auth > 10)
```

is false.

Similarly, the second loop would never be entered, as:

```
y == 0
```

And the condition:

```
if (y > 5)
```

is false.

### Flushing stdin:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

is undefined behaviour.

- *Once the abstract state machine reaches undefined behaviour, no further assumption about the continuation of the execution of the program can be made.*

---

Aside:

### Implementation-defined definition of `main`:

From `C11`:

> The function called at program startup is named main. The
> implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be
> defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any
> names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are
> declared):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

> or equivalent;10) or in some other implementation-defined manner.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your variables? Your first while loop `while(auth > 10);`, but auth = 4. Maybe you meant `while(auth < 10);`. Same for `while (y > 5)`,, because y = 0

Comment: It made the while loop not work instead